# How to show only one Item at a time in React native's FlatLists?

Tags: css, react-native, design-patterns, react-native-flatlist

I would really like to make this design but I don't know how to implement it in code, any suggestions?The issue is:I don't know how to show only one item at a time on the FlatList and how to make the centered item look closer.Lastly,How can I make the scroll go from one item to the other,without beeing sort of in the middle?
I tried looking online but I haven't been able to find what I need, if you found something please let me know.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

A list that allows both dragging and pressing a button.
For that i would use a horizontal `FlatList`. Then, make each item in the list take up 100% of the screen width and use the `FlatList`'s `ref` param to scroll to the next item in the list when pressing a button and have a `useState` to keep track of which index the user is at to align button and swiping.

Heres how i would do it.

**Get 100% screen width**

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

**Set up horizontal FlatList**

The key here is the params: `pagingEnabled` and `horizontal`.

`onViewableItemsChanged` is called whenever focused item changes.

`useCallback` is for optimization. import it with `useState`

```
// Method passed to FlatList. Displays the data's text.
const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => (
      <View style={[styles.card, { width }]}>
        <Text style={styles.cardItem}>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
    ),
    []
  );

<FlatList
  ref={flatListRef} // Reference to list. Used to scroll to specific items.
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled // cause snapping to items
  data={data}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  onViewableItemsChanged={onScroll} // Calling with anonymous function here causes issues
  viewabilityConfig={{
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 100,
  }}
/>
```

**Button**

Using the flatListRef and my useState, to scroll to the next index and keep track of where the user is at.

`import React, { useState, useRef, useCallbac } from 'react';`

`const flatListRef = useRef(null);`

`const [currentSectionIndex, setCurrentSectionIndex] = useState(0);`

```
  const onButtonPress = useCallback(() => {
    if (currentSectionIndex === data.length - 1) {
      // What you want to do at the end of the list.
    } else if (flatListRef.current) {
      // Go to the next item
      flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
        index: currentSectionIndex + 1,
      });
      setCurrentSectionIndex(currentSectionIndex + 1);
    }
  }, [currentSectionIndex, data.length]);
```

**OnScroll function**

We wanted to allow dragging and pressing a button to go move on in the list.
So when the user scrolls, we use this function, which we passed to the `FlatList`s `onViewableItemsChanged`

```
// When scrolling set useState to keep track of where the user is at.
  const onScroll = useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length === 1) {
      setCurrentSectionIndex(viewableItems[0].index);
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a carousel. Please refer to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel) library.

Comment: use pagingEnabled & horizontal in flatlist tag..